# How to change the default git-flow remote server name in git-flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I know how to rename a remote server, the question is I have to?

I am used to git, but I decided to try git flow.

The command I would use in git is `git pull feature/my-feature` and it would work since I already `git checkout -b feature/my-feature` and `git branch --set-upstream-to gitlab/feature/my-feature`, but when I try `git flow feature track my-feature` I got the following error `Fatal: Could not fetch branch 'feature/my-feature' from remote 'origin'`. I think it happens because git flow try by default to pull from origin. I would like to know if I can change this default behavior since I don't use the **origin** name.

Comment: Please do not repeat your own https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394769/git-flow-how-to-change-the-track-default-remote-repository-name. You should delete it first, or wait for it to be reopened.

Comment: ok, I just deleted it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for doing that.